# Equation with Logarithm: $\log_x3+\log_x12 = 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given is the equation:

$$\log_x3+\log_x12 = 2$$

How do I solve it? My idea was to use the formula $\log_a(b) = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$ but that does not seem to help here.

Comment: Your idea is fine. Keep running with it.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\log_x3 + \log_x12 = \log_x (3 \times 12) = \log_x 36$.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is feasible indeed!
Using the formula $\log_ab=\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$, we get $$\frac{\ln 3}{\ln x}+\frac{\ln 12}{\ln x}=2 \\ \frac{\ln 3+\ln 12}{\ln x}=2 \\ \frac{\ln(3\times 12)}{\ln x}=2 \\ \ln x=\frac 12\times \ln36 \\ \ln x=\ln{36^\frac 12} \\ \ln x = \ln 6 \\ x=6$$
Of course, change of base to natural logarithm is not a must in this question as in the answer given by @Ross B. But I would like to tell you that your approach is definitely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way is easier to understand:
$$\log_x3+\log_x12=2$$
$$\therefore\quad x^{\log_x3+\log_x12}=x^2$$
$$\therefore\quad x^{\log_x3}\cdot x^{\log_x12}=x^2$$
$$\therefore\quad 3\cdot12=x^2$$
$$\therefore\quad x^2=36=6^2$$
Since $x$ must be positive (since $\log_x$ must be defined), you get $x=6$.

Answer (score 0):

my answer,

$\log_x3+\log_x12=2$

$\log_x(3\times 12)=2\log_xx$

$\log_x(36)=\log_x(x^2)$

compare the numbers on both the sides,

$36=x^2\ \ \ \ $ forall $(0<x<1$ or $x>1)$

$x=6$

Comment: Isn't your answer similar to @RossB.'s?

Comment: Oops! I didn't see that before posting my answer. should i delete it? @MohsenShahriari

Comment: That's up  to you!